# Как поменять цвет выделенной строки dbgrid в зависимости от значения?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

Хочу сделать в dbgrid, чтобы выделялась цветом строка если в столбце "Транзакция" значение было "аннуляция, обмен, МСО или возврат" как это сделать? Знаю, что наверно надо в DBGrid1DrawColumnCell что-то написать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if DM.query.fieldbyname('operations').asstring='аннуляция'  then 
DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clSkyBlue;

if DM.query.fieldbyname('operations').asstring='возврат'  then 
DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clred;

TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect,DataCol,Column,State);
```

Comment: Напишите подробнее, куда этот код должен быть вставлен

Comment: в DBGrid1DrawColumnCell